# is this correct? $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

My instructor wrote

$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

I doubt it is incorrect.

Is it?

Comment: Just try some numbers, and you'll see?

Comment: That won't establish that it's correct.

Comment: @Shaun Yes, but it will establish it if it is incorrect.

Comment: True, @projectilemotion

Comment: Use the binomial coefficient definition of "n choose k" (being n factorial divided by k factorial times n minus k factorial) and you can use some algebra and try to establish the equivalence.

Comment: Try $n=3$ and $k=2$.

Comment: It might be good to say *why* you doubt it's correct (unless you're skeptical of everything your professor writes) -- did you see a different formula elsewhere? Did you try an example that didn't work? Edit: although now I see you "doubt it is *in*correct", so the whole thing is odd.

Comment: I am wondering if your prof meant to write something like. $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$

Answer (score 3):

$$3=\binom{3}{2}\neq\binom31-\binom21=3-2=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Search Pascal's rule , i think your assumption is wrong.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: thank you so much , i didn't know anything , i couldn't even write the answer.